# What to do in case that the first element in a quicksort algorithm happens to be the smallest value

Tags: algorithm, math, quicksort

I tried looking through my lovely textbook (with no avail) and online. According to the book I'm working off by Cormen we are to use the first element in an array as the pivot. I'm just stuck on what to do since the first element happens to be 1. 
 
The array looks as follows: 
[1, 16, 2, 3, 14, 5, 12, 7, 10, 8, 9, 17, 19, 21, 23, 26, 27] 
 
Again, the problem with the algorithm in the book is that it chooses the first element as the pivot. And once we have compared 1 to all the other elements and find that there is no other element smaller than or equal to then we are to swap the pivot and the middle element of the sub arrays, where subarray on the left is smaller than the pivot and the subarray on the right is greater than the pivot. But if our pivot IS 1 then there is no way we can swap. Really confused, any help would be great. The title of the book is Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition in case someone out there is familiar with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No difference from the normal case: just treat the left part as empty and do quicksort on the right part which is the subarray from 1.

This is not a special case. In fact, when the input is sorted, the naive quicksort degenerates into a `O(N^2)` sorting algorithm. Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot):

> In very early versions of quicksort, the leftmost element of the partition would often be chosen as the pivot element. Unfortunately, this causes worst-case behavior on already sorted arrays, which is a rather common use-case. The problem was easily solved by choosing either a random index for the pivot, choosing the middle index of the partition or (especially for longer partitions) choosing the median of the first, middle and last element of the partition for the pivot (as recommended by R. Sedgewick).

Comment: +1 for explaining why this is not a special case and that it is in fact a weakness of quicksort.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very well explained answer. Helped out really much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something known as the rule of three. Pick the first value, middle value and last value in the array and choose one of those as the pivot candidate. This doesn't guarantee that you will get the best pivot but it lowers the chances of getting a really bad pivot.

Comment: Also suggest including note explaining QS is not secure; attacker can slow it down by putting bad pivots in place in array.

Comment: A further approach is to randomize the array before sorting.